Large ATMU trades : were they sold calls or a bull call spread?
Here's all the options trades for ATMU on 2024-03-21 that had a premium greater than $10,000:

I've highlighted two that were both of size 10,000.
In both of those, the price is closer to the 'bid'. I.e. they would seem to be sold calls.
However, someone with a lot of options flow experience believes that these two are actually a bull call spread.
I.e. they believe the trader bought the 30 and sold the 35.
Question
Is there anything in the data to suggest that these might be a 30->35 bull call spread and not sold calls?
Points to consider
Points in favor of them being a bull call spread

condition is 133 (MULTI_LEG_FLOOR_TRADE)
trades were put on within 1 millisecond of each other
both trades were of the same size (10,000)

Points in favor of both being sold calls

price was closer to bid in both cases

Price chart
Here's the ATMU daily chart with the March 21st candle highlighted:

Here's a zoom with March 21st highlighted. The vertical line shows the approximate time that the two 10,000 size trades were placed.

All options trades chart
Here's all the options trades since December plotted on a chart. The two 10,000 size trades on March 21st are highlighted:

Options price chart
On the left is the price action of the 30 strike call.
On the right is the price action of the 35 strike call.
In both cases, the March 21st area is highlighted.


Every trade has a buyer and a seller so if a trade takes place at the bid, it means that a seller is willing to cross the spread and accept the bid.  With liquid actions, price improvement is quite frequent with spreads. so don't assume that both trades are buys.

What was the trader's OI before this? It's conceivable that they held the 30 strike and decided to trade it out to buy the 35. Without IV and the Greeks I probably couldn't tell you what the smart money was doing. They might even have been the aggressor if the surface had moved
